# Variable Reference Elements of Lists in R

Tags: r, list, variables, dataframe

I have been using R for a number of years now and I keep expecting to stumble upon the answer to this basic question somewhere but somehow I can't seem to find it anywhere.

How do you use a variable to target the elements of a dataframe or list?

The best I have come up with is this awkward formation.

For instance:

```
a=list(A=1:100, B=letters)
c=eval(parse(text="a$A"))
```

I could then sub out the a with "a" with a "b" if I wanted to check what the A element of the b string is.  Likewise, I would like an easy method to apply changes to an element of a.

Comment: I don't see why a$A wouldn't work in your example.

Comment: What exactly is your question? `a$A` with give you the `A` vector from the `a` list. You don't need the `eval(parse(text="a$A"))` to get this. Similarly with `b$A`, etc.

Comment: Maybe the op is looking for `get`?

Comment: the title of the question and the question itself don't seem to match very well.  "Targeting the elements of a list or data frame" sounds like you want `target <- "A"; a[[target]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your indexer is a string, then you can do this:

```
index <- "A"
a_list <- list(A=1:100, B=letters)
a_list[[index]]
```

The case for data frames is similar; you have a choice to two syntaxes.

```
a_data_frame <- data.frame(A = 1:26, B = letters)
a_data_frame[, index]
a_data_frame[[index]]
```